# Embedding a .dylib inside a framework for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, dynamic-library

I've been trying to submit a Swift app with an Obj-C Dynamic Library (.dylib) which keeps getting rejected by the iOS App Store with error messages such as

> Invalid Swift Support - The files libswiftDarwin.dylib,
>   libswiftDispatch.dylib, libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib,
>   libswiftUIKit.dylib, libswiftCore.dylib, libswiftFoundation.dylib,
>   libswiftQuartzCore.dylib, libswiftObjectiveC.dylib,
>   libswiftCoreImage.dylib aren’t at the expected location
>   /Payload//Frameworks. Move the file to the expected
>   location, rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of
>   Xcode, and resubmit it

From the Apple docs at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2435/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017543-CH1-PROJ_CONFIG-APPS_WITH_DEPENDENCIES_BETWEEN_FRAMEWORKS the error "**may indicate your app is embedding a dynamic library that is not packaged as a framework. Dynamic libraries outside of a framework bundle, which typically have the file extension .dylib, are not supported on iOS, watchOS, or tvOS, except for the system Swift libraries provided by Xcode.**"

So the next step was to embed the Dynamic Library (as a subproject) within a Cocoa Touch Framework project. Once that was set up, although the framework built fine, I got stuck on "symbol not found" errors for the imported dylib classes.

I would like to know the steps required to achieve this project structure, or if its even possible on iOS.

Comment: Be sure that the application project has the Dynamic Library as dependency. I think you can check in XCode the link command and it should contain --framework YouFramework.

Comment: any update on this? I am currently facing the same problem with converting dylib -> framework. In the Cocoa Touch Framework project in xcode the dylib is linked (in Linked Libs and Frameworks section)  but when i check the size of the Framework at the end that is built it has only 50KB although the dylib is around 4MB.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to submit an app with a .dylib by creating a framework first.
I first tried the method described in the apple documentation, but got errors when submitting to the store ( "invalid bundle. the bundle at xyz.framework contains disallowed file 'Frameworks' )

What i did was use lipo to manually package my .dylib into a framework.

```
$ lipo -create mylib.dylib -output mylib
```

Now you get a binary file called 'mylib'
Create a folder called mylib.framework and put the binary file in it.
Then add an Info.plist ( you can just copy and modify one from an existing framework. ) In the Info.plist, fill out the fields for your framework. The main  one to update or add is "Executable" which should be the name of that binary file.

I had another issue where another framework I was using was referencing my original .dylib, which is gone and now inside the framework. To fix this I used the "install_name_tool" to modify the other framework to look for my new framework.

```
$ cd OtherLib.framework 
$ install_name_tool -change @rpath/mylib.dylib @rpath/mylib.framework/mylib OtherLib
```

You can read more about that tool in this good blog post:
https://medium.com/@donblas/fun-with-rpath-otool-and-install-name-tool-e3e41ae86172

Comment: What if we have 2 dylib files, one for simulator and one for real device, how can we merge the 2 dylib as one framework? and Xcode will switch between dylib files

Comment: @HassanTaleb I think this is what an XCFramework does

Comment: @Adamski Yes but when using XCFramework, apple reject the build, with this error: ITMS-90426: Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.

Comment: After creating the framework and when using it, I got this error message in the Xcode console: ```Library not loaded: '@rpath/mylib.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/…/TestProject.app/TestProject'
  Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/system/introspection/mylib.dylib' (no such file)``` How can we fix this?