# Used dylib in my IOS framework getting error after App lauch

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, runtime-error, dylib

I have an embedded dylib in my IOS framework and trying use this framework in my application after launch is giving me an error.

```
Error:
dyld: Library not loaded:*.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/43345D9E-F58D-4FBD-9C22-DD2554AE0484/COCO.app/Frameworks/*.framework/cocosdk
  Reason: image not found
```

.dylib is embedded in "Framework" folder in my IOS framework.
things I've tried:

1. install_name_tool -change oldpath newpath libname
2. The framework already present in Embedded Binarie
3. Present in Build Phases Copy Files to Framework
4. Added Runpath search path as `"@rpath/*.dylib", "@executable_path/Frameworks", "@executable_path/Frameworks/*.framework/Frameworks/*.dylib", "@rpath/Frameworks/*.framework/Frameworks/*.dylib"`
5. Added same path in Dynamic Lib install name
6. Deleted all Derived Data
7. Clean the project and tried 
   8.'Build Libraries for Distribution' == true.

Comment: Are you creating a XCFramework?

Comment: Possible solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/62962630/13690635

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue recently, when switching from Fat/Universal binary to creating a XCFramework.

Check in your framework project if 'Build Libraries for Distribution' == true.

Comment: other things, is the framework target swift version and iOS versions higher than the Xcode project importing the framework? or the test device you're running on?

Comment: My framework and application ios minimum support version is 11.0 my test device version is ios 13.0