# Create framework including .dylib and it's headers for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, dylib, xcode12

I need to create a mylib.framework,  which is gonna include `mylib.dylib` with some header files(`mylib.h` and others). This framework I'm gonna include in another demo app. Just want to know if it is possible and how it must be done?

I tried 2 methods with Xcode 12 and command lines :

1st I created an Xcode framework project and imported headers and dylib. But the produced mylib.framework seems to have access to method definition from mylib.h but not it's binary inside dylib. I got this error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_mylib_open", referenced from:
      -[ViewController init:] in ViewController.o
```

2nd method, I followed [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53818772/embedding-a-dylib-inside-a-framework-for-ios).

Created same

```
lipo -create mylib.dylib  -output mylib
```

when adding headers, Info.plist manually, but didn't get the expected result again. This time the demo build perfectly headers seems OK . But when it runs on iPhone I get `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` and looking deeper I saw this `dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/mylib.dylib`.

Some idea ? Is it possible?