# Proper way of embedding dylib into an iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect, dylib

I have a project which consist of three elements:
C source code that is compiled to .dylib
Swift framework used to provide user-friendly swift API for .dylib
iOS app consuming both .dylib and swift proxy

I have added both swift proxy and .dylib as "Framework and libraries" dependency to iOS app project. Things work as expected on my iPhone. However when I attemt to send my app to Apple Store Connect I get following error:

```
ITMS-90429: Invalid Swift Support - The files libswiftDarwin.dylib, libswiftDispatch.dylib, libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib, libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib, libswiftCore.dylib, libswiftFoundation.dylib, libswiftObjectiveC.dylib aren’t at the expected location /Payload/Runner.app/Frameworks. Move the file to the expected location, rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode, and resubmit it.
```

I figured this can be caused by .dylib file being embedded directly in iOS app, so I tried to embed .dylib into swift framework. Then I made iOS app embedding only swift framework, which consist of .dylib file. However I am getting following error in this configuration:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libX.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/.../swiftProxy.framework/swiftProxy
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
  /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/.../swiftProxy.framework/Frameworks/libX.dylib: code signature in (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/.../swiftProxy.framework/Frameworks/libX.dylib) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.
```

This doesn't make sense for me, but I figured this is not the right way.

So the question is: how do I properly embed dylib so that it can be put on Apple Store Connect and then on Testflight?

I'm aware that this question was asked at least once, but there is no decent answer. Here for example: [How to properly embed 3rd party .dylib files in iOS app project for App Store release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48701584/how-to-properly-embed-3rd-party-dylib-files-in-ios-app-project-for-app-store-re)

Thank you

Comment: See this answer for a possible solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/62962641/211098

Answer (score 0):

You have added the Swift libraries in here: /Payload/Runner.app/Frameworks.
The error you're getting is because of Invalid structure:
Swift libraries structure should be:

```
iOS.app -> Payload
        -> SwiftSupport -> swiftLibraries.dylib
```

Then resign the app and before that make sure `.DS_Store` file has been deleted.